# GIF image not displaying when added via CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a GIF image to my webpage via CSS, the size of the image should be `100px X 100px`.

The file structure is as follows:

```
Folder:
   /index.html
   /car.gif
```

I have added the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtxg2jz5/) of the code. Can someone correct it? The GIF is not getting displayed on `index.html`:

Code

```
<html>
  <head>
<style type="text/css">
      #position {
     background-image: url('car.gif'); 
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        position: absolute;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    dd
    <div id="position"></div>

ss
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the css? Not only in the question, but also in 'real life'. Since you have just the file name without a path, the image must be in the same folder as the css file (if it's a separate css, hard to tell from the fiddle).

Comment: I have added the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image (car.gif) must reside in the same directory as the CSS if you do not specify an absolute path. For this reason, the JS fiddle is useless. Check to make sure that your files are in the places you suggested they are in.

You also might benefit from a more explicit background statement, such as:

```
background: url('car.gif') top left no-repeat transparent;
```

Moreover, if your image's native size is 100px by 100px, you will need to resize it to see it properly:

```
background-size: 25px 25px;
```

I updated the other fiddle to include a more relevant version for your question:
http://jsfiddle.net/qtxg2jz5/6/

To answer Astro's comment, I can't comment on posts because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: the CSS is in the same HTML file. I have a folder called 'MyFolder', and inside i have my `index.html` (i have also have the css inside this), and the GIF file resides here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file `car.gif` is exist at the same directory or use absolute url to the image

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtxg2jz5/4/)

Comment: I think, its problem finding that GIF file. I have it in the same folder where index.html resides. No idea why the CSS potion of the index.html can't find it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code in my browser by replacing an image from my desktop and Image was showing up.
Once just make a change to its width and height :

```
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
```

to

```
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
```

Also Once Check this...

Ex : If our Page Url is :

```
  www.yoursite.com/css/index.php
```

make sure car.gif can be accessed if you replace index.php with car.gif,

```
  www.yoursite.com/css/cars.gif
```

is accessible or not.

Thats nothing but means that that file should be in same folder..

try them and hope you will get results you need..